# Center align outputs in ipython notebook

Tags: python, css, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to center align the outputs (which includes text and plots) in my `ipython notebook`. Is there a way in which I can add styling in the same notebook for the same? Code or screenshot examples would greatly help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try running this in a code-cell to override the default CSS for an output cell:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

CSS = """
.output {
    align-items: center;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

**Example**
[image: Center align output Jupyter notebook]

You can see here that the right side of the table is cut-off a bit and the string that is printed wraps to the next line. This can be fixed by playing around with the CSS a bit, but you'll have to customize it to your own output.

In my case, I added the following lines to the CSS:

```
div.output_area {
    width: 30%;
}
```

resulting in the following output:

[image]