# How do I center the outputs on a Python Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I have a report that I have created in a Jupyter Notebook. I want the outputs (plots) to be centered for aesthetic reasons.

I have tried the answer given here:

[Centering output on IPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782317/centering-output-on-ipython-notebook)

However this one does not work.

I did find this which works on Stackoverflow ([Center align outputs in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848219/center-align-outputs-in-ipython-notebook))

```
CSS = """
.output {
    align-items: center;
}
"""

HTML('<style>{}</style>'.format(CSS))
```

However, whilst it centers the plots, when the plot is wide and doesn't need to be centered, it extends it and makes it wider than the page which I dont want. I have tried adjusting the output margin area like it said, but it either pushes it to the left again or squishes it to the point that it needs scroll bars (again I dont want that)

[image]

Anyone got any suggestions? I thought this would be standard and easy but apparently not (A way to center only a code block would be a perfect workaround if what I want is not possible?)

I.e. center this table:

[image]

Which is produced by this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a01) 

new_df01 = df[['Call','FirstReceivedDate','Value']]
new_df01['month'] = pd.Categorical(new_df01['FirstReceivedDate'].dt.strftime('%b'), 
                                         categories=vals, ordered=True) 

groupA01 = new_df01.groupby(['Call']).agg({'Value':sum, 'FirstReceivedDate':'count'}).rename(columns={'FirstReceivedDate':'Count'})
groupA01['Value'] = groupA01['Value'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)

def hover(hover_color="#F1C40F"):
    return dict(selector="tr:hover",
                props=[("background-color", "%s" % hover_color)])

styles2 = [
    hover(),
    dict(selector="th", props=[("font-size", "80%"),
                               ("font-family", "Gill Sans MT"),
                               ("color",'white'),
                               ('background-color', 'rgb(11, 48, 79)'),
                               ("text-align", "center")]),
    dict(selector="td", props=[("font-size", "75%"),
                               ("font-family", "Gill Sans MT"),
                               ("text-align", "center")]),
    dict(selector="tr", props=[("line-height", "11px")]),
    dict(selector="caption", props=[("caption-side", "bottom")])
]


html2 = (groupA01.style.set_table_styles(styles2)
          .set_caption(""))
html2
```

Thank you!

Adding code to show plotting of Heatmap:

```
dfreverse = df_hml.values.tolist()
dfreverse.reverse()

colorscale = [[0,'#FFFFFF'],[0.5, '#454D59'], [1, '#F1C40F']]

x = [threeYr,twoYr,oneYr,Yr]
y = ['March', 'February', 'January', 'December', 'November', 'October', 'September', 'August', 'July', 'June', 'May', 'April']
z = dfreverse

hovertext = list()
for yi, yy in enumerate(y):
    hovertext.append(list())
    for xi, xx in enumerate(x):
        hovertext[-1].append('Count: {}<br />{}<br />{}'.format(z[yi][xi],yy, xx))

data = [plotly.graph_objs.Heatmap(z=z,
                                  colorscale=colorscale,
                                  x=x,
                                  y=y,
                                  hoverinfo='text',
                                  text=hovertext)]

layout = go.Layout(
    autosize=False,
    font=Font(
        family="Gill Sans MT",
        size = 11
    ),
    width=600,
    height=450,
    margin=go.Margin(
        l=0,
        r=160,
        b=50,
        t=100,
        pad=3
    ),
        xaxis=dict(
        title='',
        showgrid=False,
        titlefont=dict(
           # family='Gill sans, monospace',
            size=12,
            #color='#7f7f7f'
        ),
        showticklabels=True,
        tickangle=25,
        tickfont=dict(
            family="Gill Sans MT",
            size=12,
            color='black'
        ),
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='',
        showgrid=False,
        titlefont=dict(
            #family='Gill sans',
            #size=12,
            #color='#7f7f7f'
        ),
        showticklabels=True,
        tickangle=25,
        tickfont=dict(
            family="Gill Sans MT",
            size=12,
            color='black'
        ),
)
)

fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig,config={"displayModeBar": False},show_link=False,filename='pandas-heatmap')
```

Comment: Do you just want to centre the output in the live version of the notebook, or do you want it centred after `nbconvert` converts it to e.g. HTML, PDF? Or do you want it centred for both scenarios?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response! I want it to centre the output when you export it to html through the notebook :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please tryout this class for centering your graphs, since there is no dataframe provided, I am creating a plot with a random data frame demonstrating the capabilities of the class. Please check it out.

**Code:**

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import numpy as np
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

display(HTML("""
<style>
.output {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
"""))
iplot([{"x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [3, 1, 6]}])
iplot([Box(y = np.random.randn(50), showlegend=False) for i in range(45)], show_link=False)
x = np.random.randn(2000)
y = np.random.randn(2000)
iplot([Histogram2dContour(x=x, y=y, contours=Contours(coloring='heatmap')),
       Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker=Marker(color='white', size=3, opacity=0.3))], show_link=False)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Naren, going to check it out now :)

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you for helping, your code does indeed center the outputs, but like my previous problem, when you export it to HTML it squishes the charts for some reason and adds a horizontal scroll bar :/... I really dont know why.

Comment: @ScoutEU let me export and check

Comment: Ok, thank you. As an example of what is happening... this is a picture of my HTML export (http://imgur.com/oLFdISa)

Comment: @ScoutEU you have not provided the plotting function, as to how you have used plotly to plot the data, i am talking about the iplot function you use in the end

Comment: Hey! I added another block of code showing how my heatmap was produced. Are you thinking it might be the way I am plotting it?... let me try with your code to see if I can replicate the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm... yep, your code did not squeeze the charts. Ill mark your answer as accepted and I will have to do some work as to why it is not working as intended. Thank you again Naren :)

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. It is the code I used to hide the code... I will need to find a different version. Thank you!

Comment: @ScoutEU Glad you fixed it